# Как правильно: двадцатидвухлетие или двадцати двух летие или двадцати двухлетие?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: двадцатидвухлетие или двадцати двух летие или двадцати двухлетие?

Answer (score 5):

Правильно: двадцатидвухлетие. Это тема сложных слов на основе  числительных.

Сложные слов на основе  числительных (в том числе на основе составных числительных с раздельным написанием) пишутся слитно. Они могут состоять из двух или большего количества основ.

Первым компонентом в таких словах является основа числительного (обычно в форме Р.п.),  а в качестве опорного элемента выступает существительное: стодневный, двадцатипятилетний, восьмистишие.

ДЛЯ СРАВНЕНИЯ:

РАЗДЕЛЬНО пишутся СОСТАВНЫЕ количественные числительные, а также образованные от них порядковые числительные: сорок пять, сто пятьдесят два  – составные количественные числительные, сорок пятый, сто пятьдесят второй – составные порядковые числительные.

Answer (score 2):

"Двадцатидвухлетие" - правильно.