# Двацатиоднолетие (язык сломаешь, да ещё и не грамотно по ходу =)

Tags: числительные

Слово "двадцатилетие" - корректное; "двадцатидвухлетие" - корректное (это написано на вашем сайте, внизу оставлю ссылку); "тридцатилетие" - корректное; "двадцатиоднолетие" - похоже, некорректное; тридцатиоднолетие - похоже, тоже некорректное.
 Верны ли мои предположения? Какими правилами нужно руководствоваться в подобных случаях? Хотелось бы услышать также историческую подоплёку.

Вот ссылка на вопрос о слове "двадцатидвухлетие":

([Как правильно: двадцатидвухлетие или двадцати двух летие или двадцати двухлетие?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416446/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Comment: У "не грамотно по ходу" подоплёка есть?

Answer (score 3):

В орфографическом словаре зафиксированы такие сложные числительные, как: ***двадцатиоднолетний, тридцатиоднолетний,двадцатипятилетие.***

Первые два слова образованы от соответствующих существительных - ***тридцатиоднолетие, двадцатиоднолетие.***

О правилах образования таких числительных см. в ответе Vera по вашей ссылке.

> Слитно или раздельно? Орфографический словарь-справочник. — М.: Русский язык. Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Какалуцкая. 1998.
>
> Русский орфографический словарь: около 180 000 слов / Российская академия наук. Институт русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова / О.Е. Иванова, В.В. Лопатин (отв. ред.), И.В. Нечаева, Л.К. Чельцова

Answer (score 2):

1) Никто официально не запрещает слово "двадцатиоднолетний", иногда оно даже используется в текстах, например:

В 1908 году он, двадцатиоднолетний, играл в сборной страны, когда Дания завоевала серебряные медали на Олимпиаде в Лондоне. [Д. С. Данин. Нильс Бор (1969-1975).  Рональдо! Двадцатиоднолетний гений и 90 минут, которые потрясли мир.

РУССКИЙ ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКИЙ СЛОВАРЬ РАН: двадцатиоднолетний (21-летний). Схема образования обычная, как и у других сложных слов на основе числительных, нельзя назвать его неграмотным.

2) Но почему-то нам это слово не нравится, кажется некорректным. **Можно предположить, что все дело в в слове "один", которое занимает особое место в языке.**

Во-первых, счетно-местоименное слово "один" может являться КОЛИЧЕСТВЕННЫМ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫМ: один, один день. Но слово "один" может также быть ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМ, МЕСТОИМЕНИЕМ,  ЧАСТИЦЕЙ, например:   Выхожу один я на дорогу. Мы с другом живем в одном доме. Повесть Салтыкова-Щедрина «История одного города».  Кумиры сердца сберегу я одни, одни в любви моей.

Во-вторых, особая традиция употребления: однолетнее растение - термин (существующее один год), но: годовалый ребенок (в возрасте одного года). Сравнить: однолетнее растение, двадцатиоднолетнее растение, как-то созвучно получается.

Comment: Вера, автора интересовало корректность слова двадцатиодн**олетие"***, а не "двадцатиоднолетний"

Comment: А какая разница? Двадцатиоднолетний - двадцатиоднолетие, существительное мотивировано прилагательным. В текстах встречается, например: "Получив на свое двадцатиоднолетие обещанную тысячу, Джулия принялась курить, как паровоз".

Comment: Вы правы, конечно. То же я написал в ответе. Просто автора интересовало двадцатиоднолетие, поэтому я сказал, что лучше написать про сущ-е, чтобы автор понял, что прил-е мотивировано существительным.

Comment: Автор молчит, не хочет с нами разговаривать. Мне, например, не очень ясно, какую "историческую подоплёку" он имел в виду. А вот еще интересно, что означает "не грамотно по ходу". И почему используется раздельное написание частицы НЕ?

Comment: Да, Вера, вы абсолютно правы: те же вопросы возникли и у меня.